# Multiples annotations (with a data.frame) in dygraphs with R

Tags: r, annotations, dygraphs

There is a package in R for dygraphs, and it is possible to add annotations: https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-annotations.html

```
dygraph(presidents, main = "Quarterly Presidential Approval Ratings") %>%
  dyAxis("y", valueRange = c(0, 100)) %>%
  dyAnnotation("1950-7-1", text = "A", tooltip = "Korea") %>%
  dyAnnotation("1965-1-1", text = "B", tooltip = "Vietnam")
```

I would like to how it is possible to create a data.frame in order to organise all annotations and add with a single dyAnnotation option. I tried:

```
dygraph(presidents, main = "Quarterly Presidential Approval Ratings") %>%
  dyAxis("y", valueRange = c(0, 100)) %>%
  dyAnnotation(c("1950-7-1","1965-1-1"), text = c("A","B"), tooltip = c("Korea","Vietnam"))
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

Step 1. Create a basic `dygraph` without annotations and save it as object (not really required but creates shorter strings in Step 2):

```
dygraph(presidents, main = "Quarterly Presidential Approval Ratings") %>%
  dyAxis("y", valueRange = c(0, 100)) -> graph
```

Step 2. Create two (if you want `tooltips` also create three) vectors with `dates` and `texts` for your annotations. Then create below `string`:

```
 dates<-c("1950-7-1","1965-1-1","1972-1-1")
 texts<-c("a","bb","cc")

 my_code<-paste("graph %>%",
 paste0("dyAnnotation('",dates,"',text='",texts,"')",collapse = " %>% "))
```

You will get something like this:

```
"graph %>% dyAnnotation('1950-7-1',text='a') %>% dyAnnotation('1965-1-1',text='bb') %>% dyAnnotation('1972-1-1',text='cc')"
```

Step 3. Use `eval` and `parse` functions:

```
  eval(parse(text = my_code))
```

[image: Multiply annotations]

If you want to create an object containing this graph chcnage the `string` in Step 2:

```
my_code<-paste("graph2<- graph %>%",
  paste0("dyAnnotation('",dates,"',text='",texts,"')",collapse = " %>% "))
```